# How to run a command file in PuTTY using automatic login in a command prompt?

Tags: command-line, ssh, unix, putty

I am using the following to login automatically to a remote server and then run commands listed in a `commands.txt`, like this:

```
C:\path\to\putty.exe -load "[Sessionname]" -l [user] -pw [password] -m C:\path\to\commands.txt
```

`commands.txt` contains the following:

```
ps -elf|grep 'sometext'
```

However, when I try to do so a new window for PuTTY appears, but it closes and exits instantly after login. As a result, I cannot see the output of the command(s).

I don't understand what's going on here. Am I wrong in my approach or do I need to take more steps to make the PuTTY window pause for some time before exiting?

Comment: Consider to use **Plink.exe** instead (typically bundled with Putty, remember to include in PATH). I spent 2 hours googling how to specify rsa key in a command line for PuTTY because it's unsafe to hard code passwords. I overlooked Plink solution because, I thought the call had to start with putty. Check answer below mentioning Plink. e.g. `Plink.exe -ssh host -l user -i c:\Users\myName\.ssh\myGeneratedPuttyKey.ppk

Answer (score 12):

First you would need to create a separate file containing all the commands you would like to be executed.

Example: I would like to download and install [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) on my domain using PuTTY. To do that you must:

First create a .txt file. Within that file are the commands. Mine are: "**drush dl drupal**" next line, "**drush si --account-name=[account name] --account-pass=[account pass] --db-url=mysql://[user]:[pass]@localhost/[database name] --y**"

After saving that file, you are now going to create a [BAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file or type it in the CMD prompt:

- ssh.cmd
- @echo on [for you to see what's going on]
- [Navigate to your PuTTY installation. Mine is:] cd C:\Program Files\Putty
- Start `putty.exe -ssh [domain name] -l [username] -pw [password] -m [the directory of the .txt file you created which contains the codes you want to be executed]`

Comment: The -m option does not work for me. it is giving out an error saying cannot open command file <path to my text file>

Comment: @user590849 does the path to your command text file have any white space? Because I just

Answer (score 11):

You should use `plink.exe` (a command-line interface to the PuTTY back ends) and not `putty.exe`

You get that from the [PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

**Without plink:**

It seems the only way is to use the `-log <logfile>` options and then print its content and delete it.

Comment: I cannot use plink or other command line interfaces. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: @supportpb "I cannot use plink" -- why? what happens if you try?

Comment: @gertvdijk what happens is that he gets fired for using non-approved software on corporate machines...

Comment: unsupported option: `-log`

Answer (score 3):

There would be no issue if you just want to create the batch file to open the Unix machine. Below is the example:

```
"PuTTY path" -ssh machinename -l username -pw password
```

The PuTTY path should be in double quotes, like "C:\Program Files\putty\putty.ext"

machinename = machinename without double quotes

password = with quotes

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems good, however, there's one default setting in the behaviour that's causing you trouble here and probably making you believe nothing's happening.

> However, when I try to do so a new window for PuTTY appears, but closes and exits instantly after login

Your session ends immediately after the command was executed, and PuTTY closes the window by default. See the [documentation of PuTTY](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/puttydoc.txt) on how to change this behaviour for your session.

```
4.1.3 `Close Window on Exit'

   Finally in the Session panel, there is an option labelled `Close
   Window on Exit'. This controls whether the PuTTY terminal window
   disappears as soon as the session inside it terminates.
```

Comment: Interesting, but that will affect manual sessions as well...

Comment: @AviramSegal It's a session setting. Just duplicate the session configuration, say `session-noclose` and use that one in scripting.

Comment: oh session setting, then yes that will work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Aviram's answer:

Below is the example how you will run PuTTY commands from command prompt:

- First go to the PuTTY installation directory, for example `C:\Program Files\PuTTY`, and then execute the below command:

  > plink.exe **-ssh** *server_ip* **-P** *port_no* **-l** *user_name* **-pw** *password*