# Run a single command on putty start

Tags: windows, command-line, putty

I want putty to run a single command after login when its start up and then get control of the console.

Let's say every time I need to goto a specific directory to run some command there.
The command I execute will vary time to time but I need to go to that specific directory every time : lets say the directory is `a/b/c/`

So I need to run a

```
cd /a/b/c
```

command  after every time i login.

currently I am using :

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\putty.exe [myhost] -l [user] -pw [password]
```

As the `Target` value In `putty.exe` shortcut file. Which working fine.

But now I want to execute a

```
cd /a/b/c
```

command after login automatically, Is it possible?

I have tried as suggested [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/515601/how-to-run-a-command-file-in-putty-using-automatic-login-in-a-command-prompt) . But its execute the command and then exit putty. I don't want the putty to exit after the command has been executed.

Comment: Assuming the remote system is unix-y and your shell is bash, add the cd command  to your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: little complex for me.? can you explain please and  where is the `~/.bash_profile `?

Comment: Before that, are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 5):

You need to write your command in a file first. Then you can use `-m` option of `putty.exe`:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@192.168.56.1 -P 22 -pw password -m C:\fileWithCommand
```

It depends on the system's OS which you want to access via SSH whether it is possible to write even a batch of commands in this file.

Above method can execute whole scripts but closes the session when terminated. If you want to have the output, download [plink.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html):

```
plink.exe -ssh user@192.168.56.1 -P 22 -pw password echo test
```

This command prints `test`.

`-P 22` is not necessary in the case your port is `22`.

Comment: yes tried that. That exit putty after execution of that command . any alternative.?

Comment: Thanks for your nice effort. I ran your command from command prompt. yes it does print `test`. But i don't want just the output. I also want to use the command interface like regular, which  means executing some command by my self after that command execute. I am doing it right ? or It is possible vai putty.? or Do i have to combine putty.exe and plink.exe in some way which i dont know.? thanks again.

Comment: if we wanted to send some arguments to the shell script that run inside the putty? @h0ch5tr4355

Comment: For those who are having issue that putty exits after execution, we need to give "-t" option at the end so that the session remains interactive.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having issue that putty exits after execution when we use -m, we need to give "-t" option at the end so that the session remains interactive.

```
putty.exe -ssh example.com -m "c:\pathOfCommandFile\cmd.txt" -t
```

So on windows, basically we can create a shortcut and in its property put the whole statement as above. In cmd.txt put the command to execute. You may have to give absolute path of putty.exe (example: C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe)